# Cassandra query logging through spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, cassandra-2.1, spring-data-cassandra

is there any easy way to turn on query logging on cassandra through xml configuration? I'm using namespace:

```
xmlns:cassandra="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/cassandra"
```

but I can't find any suitable solution. I was trying to turn on trace through cqlsh, but it dosen't work for my app.

I was trying also to add line:

```
<logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL" level="TRACE" />
```

But also doesn't work.

My versions:
spring-data-cassandra-1.4.0
cassandra: 2.1.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check out this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies) and check if you added the query logger to your cluster definition like stated:

```
Cluster cluster = ...
QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder(cluster)
    .withConstantThreshold(...)
    .withMaxQueryStringLength(...)
.build();
cluster.register(queryLogger);
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: any application.properties solution?

Answer (score 8):

Add a `QueryLogger` *@Bean* and get the `Cluster` @Autowired in:

```
@Bean
public QueryLogger queryLogger(Cluster cluster) {
    QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder()
            .build();
    cluster.register(queryLogger);
    return queryLogger;
}
```

(+ obviously configure `QueryLogger.Builder` as required).

Don't forget to set log levels to *DEBUG*/*TRACE* in your `application.yml`:

```
logging.level.com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL: DEBUG
logging.level.com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW: TRACE
```

Voilà!

Comment: This is actually the better way because it also works if you are using CassandraClusterFactoryBean to initialize your cluster.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring Data Cassandra 2.4+ **QueryLogger** is not available anymore,  it was replaced with **RequestTracker** which can be configured in `application.yml` or overridden depending on your needs.

> The Java driver provides a RequestTracker interface. You can specify an implementation of your own or use the provided RequestLogger implementation by configuring the properties in the datastax-java-driver.advanced.request-tracker namespace. The RequestLogger tracks every query your application executes and has options to enable logging for successful, failed, and slow queries. Use the slow query logger to identify queries that are not within your defined performance.

Configuration:

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.request-tracker {
  class = RequestLogger

  logs {
    # Whether to log successful requests.
    success.enabled = true

    slow {
      # The threshold to classify a successful request as "slow". If this is unset, all
      # successful requests will be considered as normal.
      threshold = 1 second

      # Whether to log slow requests.
      enabled = true
    }

    # Whether to log failed requests.
    error.enabled = true

    # The maximum length of the query string in the log message. If it is longer than that, it
    # will be truncated.
    max-query-length = 500

    # Whether to log bound values in addition to the query string.
    show-values = true

    # The maximum length for bound values in the log message. If the formatted representation of
    # a value is longer than that, it will be truncated.
    max-value-length = 50

    # The maximum number of bound values to log. If a request has more values, the list of
    # values will be truncated.
    max-values = 50

    # Whether to log stack traces for failed queries. If this is disabled, the log will just
    # include the exception's string representation (generally the class name and message).
    show-stack-traces = true
}
```

[More details.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/core/request_tracker/)

Comment: I am using this. But, my application.conf file is not being detected. Is there a way to do this configuration in my spring application.properties file?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Spring Data for Apache Cassandra version 2.0 or higher, then you can use your logging configuration to activate CQL logging. Set the log level of `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate` to `DEBUG`, no need to mess with `QueryLogger`:

```
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate=DEBUG
```

This can, of course, be permanently done in the `application.properties`.

Comment: Except that no readable toString() has been implemented on Statement ..

Comment: @Abhijit in which file should I set the log level ?

Comment: @kayeshparvez Read the last line of my answer again, or see the other answers.

Comment: @Abhijit If I put it in application.properties then ide can not resolve that line. ide is intellij

Comment: This approach does not log the values