# Cassandra query logging: data size

Tags: logging, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

The Datastax `QueryLogger` (i.e. [Cassandra query logging through spring configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310175/1371329)) outputs good information about query timing.

> DEBUG c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL - [cluster1] [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Query completed normally, took 100 ms: SELECT * FROM my_table;

In addition to the speed of the query, I'm also interested in the size of the payload. Is there a way to log the amount of data retrieved? Something like this?

> Query completed normally, took 100 ms: SELECT * FROM my_table **returned 5MB**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated. First, you need to define what you mean by "size of the payload".

If you want the size of the encoded values in a statement, IOW, the size of the request once serialized to the wire, then you could have a look at the Java driver's [Statement.computeSizeInBytes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.12/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/Statement.html#computeSizeInBytes-com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.context.DriverContext-) method. But beware that this is driver 4.x, but you seem to be using driver 3.x.

If you want the total size of the mutation once it gets written to the disk, it's trickier. Cassandra does have an internal utility called `org.apache.cassandra.db.IMutation.dataSize()`; but it's hard to reproduce this algorithm outside of the coordinator node. [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) has a utility that tries its best to do that: [DataSizes](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk/blob/1.x/sampler/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/dsbulk/sampler/DataSizes.java). Feel free to reuse that logic in your own code.

And lastly, you would have to modify the query logging code to append the data size to the logged message. The driver doesn't do that by default.

Comment: I'm looking to get the size of the (serialized) records read from the database, in order to get an idea of how much network bandwidth a query is using. It sounds like writing the data to a flat file and looking at the file size will be the simplest way to get an estimate, though it's not an automated solution that scales well.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were interested in the size of data being written. For data being read, you can use the method implemented in DSBulk's DataSizes utility. This should give you a fairly good estimate of the amount of network bandwidth used.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to return the result/payload size using the `QueryLogger`.

I've reached out to the driver devs here at DataStax and will get them to respond with a possible solution or I will update my answer. Cheers!